# Extracting image link through regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have a bunch of links in this format

```
http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM
http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM[/IMG]
[IMG]http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM
[IMG]http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM[/IMG]
```

The IMG tags are only supplied in some cases, and I want to extract the link, i.e. `http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM` in this case. Is there an easy way to do this through regex in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying that you have the text in the question in some kind of list and they are always either in the format of:

1. Just the Url
2. the Url + partial or full tags

then the easiest thing to do is to run:

```
url = url.Replace("[IMG]", "").Replace("[/IMG]");
```

if there are no tags then there is no change, but if the tags are there they will be stripped out.

Comment: Thanks, totally blanked out on the Replace method. This is easier than using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern:

```
^(?:\[IMG\])?([^[]*)(?:\[/IMG\])?$
```

You can get the output using:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?:\[IMG\])?([^[]*)(?:\[/IMG\])?$");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // http://imgur.com/a/bwBpM
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with Oren's approach since it does the same thing without using regex (so I think it will be a bit faster?)

Comment: @Narabhut No problem. Yes, that would be faster. Happy coding.